# Multiselect dropdown option value taking only one word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a multiselect dropdown inside a table

```
<td>
<select multiple="multiple" name="multiple" id="multiple" class="required">

</select>
</td>
```

The option values are populated with json data.

```
for(var i=0;i<jsonString.length;i++){

            var name=jsonString[i].Name;
            $('#multiple').append('<option value=' + name + '>' + name + '</option>'); 
        }
```

When the user start selection i am trying to display each selected item inside a paragraph

```
<script>
function displayVals() {
  var multipleValues = $("#multiple").val() || [];
  $("p").html( " <b>Selected Properties:</b> " + 
  multipleValues.join(", "));
        }
 $("select").change(displayVals);
 displayVals();

</script>
```

But in the paragraph i get just one word per selection, not the complete name. (Say If i select "some text" i get only "some"). Can somebody point out where is the error?

Comment: Try removing space in `.join(", ")` so it will be `.join(",")`

Comment: Works fine for me. Probably just a display issue. To verify, log the `multipleValues` to the console.

Comment: It's working fine, check here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/je5VQ/1/

Comment: Its working fine... try run on other browsers..

Comment: the option value is not taking the complete name while getting populated with json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While populating with JSON data use

```
<option values= > instead of `<option value>
```

Working fine for me now.`